# I can't extend java classes in intelliJ

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I must be missing the obvious here. I have a Maven project with a bunch of dependencies defined in my pom.xml such s Spring.

[image: TwitterProfile.java] let's say I want to extend TwitterProfile. I see the class is not final but all classes appear with a lock icon.

How do I extend for instance **TwitterProfile** by say **TwitterProfileWithCustomAttribute** it would not let me.

What's going on?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to edit the code inside the jar file which is locked. You should be able to extend this in your own project.

Comment: What kind an error occurs when you write `TwitterProfileWithCustomAttribute extends TwitterProfile`

Comment: You need to be more specific... What do you mean it won't let you?

Comment: The error was TwitterProfile was not getting resolved somehow. Marked with error. After restarting IntelliJ error seemed to be shown and it was related to the lack of constructor matching parent class. Now it's resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error disappeared after restarting IntelliJ :-/

The lock in the classes I guess will be related to the fact they point to ~/.m2 maven repository which is owned by root user.